# I implemented in java code an interface defined in kotlin. Got 'void' type not allowed here

Tags: java, android, interface, kotlin

I defined a listener interface in kotlin like this

```
interface FooListener {
    fun onCall()
}
```

which I think the return type is actually Unit in kotlin

And then I implemented this interface in java

```
FooListener l = new FooListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCall() {
    }
}
```

Here the onCall function implementation is auto generated by IDE

I got an error while compiling which said

```
Error:(107, 85) error: 'void' type not allowed here
```

Can anyone help me to sort this out?

Comment: The return type is `Unit`, but it compiles to `void`, so the code is correct. I cannot reproduce it here.

Comment: @nhaarman Thanks for replying. I am actually getting confused as well. I am currently converting my android from java to kotlin during which I got this error. But anyway thank you for your time

Comment: In that case, it might be a caching problem. Try a clean rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this. I guess it's a bug of the compiler, you may try switching to a newer version.

In my IDE, my code:

[image]
[image]

Works fine.

Here I'd like to provide two solutions:

- Change `void` into `Unit`, and put `return Unit.INSTANCE;` at the end of the implementation.
- Change `fun onCall()` into `fun onCall(): Void?`, and put `return null;` at the end of the implementation.

I tried more examples, even if I write an anonymous inner class (I use IDE picture instead of code snippets to show you that the code is correct):

[image]

Or replace it with a lambda expression:

[image]

It still works fine.

If you still cannot figure out, simply use another interface provided by the standard library, like `java.util.function.Consumer`.